# How to create a thread and exit from the application without finish the thread execuation?

Tags: visual-c++, pthreads

I have created a application in VC++. and I want to run other application in thread from my application. Also without waiting the response from thread, I want to exit from my application.

I am using VC++ 6.0.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You run the other application in a separate process and then exit your process.
Threads can't run other applications. Processes are meant for running applications.

Comment: oK, I have created a process. For e.g  CString cmd = "C:\\Program Files\\WinMerge\\Merge.exe";
 STARTUPINFO siStartInfo;
 PROCESS_INFORMATION piProcInfo;
 BOOL ret= CreateProcess( NULL,
   (LPTSTR)cmd.GetBufferSetLength(cmd.GetLength()),    // application name
   NULL,        // process security attributes
   NULL,        // primary thread security attributes
   TRUE,        // handles are inherited
   0,    //DETACHED_PROCESS, // creation flags
   NULL,        // use parent's environment
   NULL,   // use parent's current directory
   &siStartInfo,  // STARTUPINFO pointer
   &piProcInfo);  //

Comment: Its return 0, any idea where I failed.

Comment: I forgot to intialize zero memory for the startinfo and procinfo